# How to convert a hex to a number that looks the same when printed in decimal?

Tags: java, hex, decimal

I have the following code in Java:

```
int hex = 0x63;
```

The decimal value of 63<sub>16</sub> is equal to 99<sub>10</sub>. I would like to convert this hex value to a decimal that is equal to 63<sub>10</sub>.

Comment: no, the hex value is 0x63, I want to have a decimal value as 63 based on the hex value

Comment: what when you have 0x1F?

Comment: only consider the digit now

Answer (score 3):

> the hex value is `0x63`, I want to have a decimal value as `63` based on the hex value

This is called a [*Binary-coded decimal (BCD)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) representation. There are many ways to convert a number from BCD to decimal. Perhaps the simplest one is to print it as hex, and then parse it back as a decimal:

```
int hex = 0x63;
int dec = Integer.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(hex), 10);
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/9x6K3z)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
int hex = 0x63;
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(hex+"", 10);
System.out.println("Decimal value is :" + decimalValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int hex = 0x63F2FC;//just an example (containg letters)
String hexStr = Integer.toHexString(hex);
String decimal = "";
char[] tmp = hexStr.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length ; i++)
    decimal += (Character.isDigit(tmp[i])?tmp[i]+"":"");
```